# TypeScript - store metadata subtype in a type without affecting the type

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it's possible to store some type metadata in a type, so it can be extracted using a type function, without actually affecting the value of the type itself.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwEMCMAeAKgPigXigbygFt4EAuKNKAXwCgbRIoBxeORVTHCqCAD2AgA7ACYBnWCVQBLQQDMIAJygAlLAH4VUcoIgA3RQG46DaCaRdBAV0IAjRVAA+E9ilHAFMgOYYDUAPR+UKIAFgD2lgA2wlB2UABWlm5QVraK9ODQxOxcbMgoZlgBUKEA1nRFAJJQ7lIQ0QDuUsDByXqKADQxlsBQlnKhCsB9CAIRIFBNUMKhEOKCoT31A2UmUABybQroWLg6+gpGq7kATNtcG-vb6YwswCdnuJR8AiLi9zLySqpQGsparfsjNdTBljhZrHYlE57m4PIJvL4iqVgUQSGDcPcTMdCoE9mkaJVgABycRgUKiURSGwRUyhKAAYwUEBG0AQ1Qy1Tpnng1WC0CZAEdLFImdFVroEBFLBAUbcAGqS6UPbjPIRiZx5Poleb1QTqAH2choQ4ckwAZi48sVEBQKUhjg1qFhXgwOOSEPxRQAQt0oBUiYQgpB6VJZFJ6ZKxlAIqFSl4oLIBlA2aJQlLgFJQoIoPU+UzmPAFVLoNNZskFlBggh9JyYtBEnUCYEAIJBNPdTPZ3OKUx81GIdmMCPZ2Kp4hheo8fgKBD0gTCTogHmluYVhCyeRz3kyoqEBAyQfQA9ssAzufhyU5hAgIA)

```
type Meta1<T> = { meta: T }

type GetMeta1<T> = T extends Meta1<infer R> ? R : never;

type type1 = number | Meta1<string>; // should be just number
type meta1 = Meta1<type1> // ok

// I tried with never, but unfortunately it does not work
type Never<T> = never;
type Meta2<T> = Never<T>
type GetMeta2<T> = T extends Meta2<infer R> ? R : never;

type type2 = number | Meta2<string>; // ok
type meta2 = Meta2<type2> // never

// It's possible to create a type to get the required type value
type GetValue<T> = T extends Meta1<unknown> ? never : T;
type type3 = GetValue<number | Meta1<string>> // number

// But I'm specifically looking for a solution where GetValue does not have to be used
// A solution where the meta type can be somehow extracted, yet does not affect the
// main type in a practical way
```

Comment: Could you please provide more explanation about the purpose ? It is a good question but I have a feeling that I'm missing something

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It's for documenting what errors a function throws. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219#issuecomment-928866237 - by the comment, the goal would be to add the error type annotation without having to use `GetFunctionResult` type - so the error annotation does not pollute the actual type.

Comment: Have you considered to use some class for `throw` object? Or a monad? Smth like https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/  Rust `Result` ? I think every approach of typing error type will be a hack. Maybe it worth using function helper for errors ? Like here tsplay.dev/NlpOrN

Comment: Yes, I have inspected it in great detail and almost wanted to implement it and I have put significant effort in the setup (even created an eslint plugin to check unchecked errors), but ultimately I discarded it. I have found that most errors I want to propagate immediately up anyway, which is practically the same as throwing. And in the few scenarios where I do need to mind the errors and process them, I can just use try / catch and mind the error codes. Now I'm just looking if there's a better way to annotate that a function may throw something than using a throws tsdoc tag.

Comment: Rust implementation is pretty good, but it's the language default and there's a sugar with ? that really does make a huge difference in making it practical.

Comment: It's not a huge priority, I could get by without documenting the thrown errors at all  (it's safe to assume that almost any function can throw, since native JS functions throw too) . But while I'm at it, I'm just wondering if something like this is possible.

Comment: seems to be that you did a great job investigating this problem. Unfortunately TypeScript has not plugin system, otherwise your approach would be a good candidate for extra flag or plugin

Comment: I submitted a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46142